# Get variable from context to angular scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling with getting **sourcePath** in controller **$scope** somehow.

I have code like this:

```
(function() {
  var sourcePath;

  sourcePath = 'app/assets/javascripts/shared/controllers/some_controller.coffee';

  angular.module("shared").controller("SomeController", function($scope) {
    // $scope._sourcePath = sourcePath;

}).call(this);
```

**Except** this `$scope._sourcePath = sourcePath;` line.

And If I manually add this to some controller then it works, but I want to refer to this sourcePath variable after controller is defined.

I want to do `angular.element(someElement).scope().somehowGetThisSourcePathVariable()`

So basically I want to get to controller context(this) when I have some controller $scope object.

Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: "I want to refer to this sourcePath variable after controller is defined." --not sure what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: angular.module("shared").value(‘sourcePath’, 'blabla'); then controller("SomeController", [ "sourcePath", "$scope", function(sourcePath, $scope) { console.log(sourcePath);

Comment: @brendan Basically I want to get somehow controller context(`this` containg `sourcePath`) when I have $scope object in hand.

Comment: or use constants if it is a constant for you.  angular.module("shared").constant(‘sourcePath’, ‘somepath’);

Comment: @AhmetZeytindalı It's not what I want. I don't want to write this sourcePath alone. I also don't want to do heavy parsing to inject it automatically. this sourcePath variable is added to every coffescript file before compilation to js in assets pipeline. I wan't to refer to it given some $scope object but I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: @Titelitury, but your variable not in `controller context` it inside `$scope` so `angular.element(someElement).scope()._sourcePath` work

Comment: @Titelitury, why you not want move this `var sourcePath;

  sourcePath = 'app/assets/javascripts/shared/controllers/some_controller.coffee';` inside controller?

Comment: anyway you can just add function to scope like: `$scope.somehowGetThisSourcePathVariable=function(){return sourcePath}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample has a syntax error. If I fix it, it works fine in plunkr.

```
(function() {
  var sourcePath;

  sourcePath = 'app/assets/javascripts/shared/controllers/some_controller.coffee';

  angular.module("shared", []).controller("SomeController", function($scope) {
    $scope._sourcePath = sourcePath;
  });

}).call(this);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ah5vrIyHJHE7BufxCrPx?p=preview

Comment: I wrote I don't want to add this to every controller manually. I'm doing framework solution to retreiving controller path from $scope and I wont tell everybody to manually change every controller file for my code to work. I prefer to do heavy parsing instead, but maybe it's possible with javascript.

Comment: @Titelitury, you can not get `sourcePath` since it simple local variable, before you assign it to `$scope` field

Comment: What @Grundy said. Since it's not an object you aren't sharing a reference. You should use `value`, `constant`, or a service like suggested in other comments.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson, you a bit wrong :-) this value cannot be sharing just because it **local variable**, and not because this _not an object_

Comment: @Grundy, I was making assumptions about the intention. Yes, it's a local variable. But even if you had all controllers pointed to it, you couldn't update the variable in one place and have it updated in all places- since it's not a reference.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson, you could this - since controllers would be use it from local scope